# Custom callout accessory from a custom view in MKMapview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, mkmapview

I am developing an app with a map view. The map view should have annotations, but the pin should always be centred and the map should scroll under it. For that, instead of adding annotation to map, I added a `UIView`(with a pin image as background) as subview to my view controller's view. Now the map view and the `UIView` are in the same hierarchy. The `UIView` is centred and the map will scroll under it. (Is there a better solution?)

Now the problem I am facing with is the callout accessory. I have the tap event on the `UIView`, where I can create a another `UIView` as callout accessory. But what would be the best option to create a callout accessory in my case. Any ideas are welcome.